# Building multiple flavors of an application with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, so I'm building a Web application using PHP and Laravel and the ultimate goal is to have a free, standard version as well as a commercial version which the user will have to pay. Of course, the commercial version will have additional features which will be locked in the community edition.

The problem here is that I have no idea how to go about this and surprisingly, I can't seem to find anything on how to intelligently develop this type of application. Having two codebase, one for each version, seems like a very bad idea. Equally, having my code riddled with "if" statements to lock features up depending on specific clients seems pretty bad too.

How does one go about developing an application with multiple flavors like this? Are there tools? Tutorials which I could read?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: In answer to Scott's comment, at the moment, we're going to manage the hosting of the application. The owner mentioned his plan to go open-source in a couple of years, but right now my main focus is to manage Community VS Commercial edition.

Comment: How about creating views for both, free and commercial version, and use router with middleware for commercial content that checks whether or not user has premium account?

Comment: One thing that was not clear to me, is this going to be hosted by you or are you allowing them to download and host this? It makes a difference in approach.

Comment: Are you going to sell the full project code or you making a SaaS?

Comment: This is not really the scope of SO questions. This question may solicit  opinion based answers

Comment: I'm aware of that, however I could not think of any other place to post my question